# If I buy golden gun for a hero, is it only for that skin or for every skin?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, if I spend my hard-earned 3000 competitive points on a golden weapon for a hero, is it locked to the skin, or available for every skin for that character?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Golden weapon skins are separate from hero skins meaning that yes, the golden weapon can be used with any hero skin.

Comment: So you only need to get it once and then you get golden weapons for all heroes?

Comment: @D.Va It is unlocked per hero, choose wisely who you want that golden weapon for.

Answer (score -7):

It's for only that skin provided that it's not just a re-colour 
If it's a re-colour then I think it's for everyone other re-colour including the original as the weapon looks the same :)

Comment: Please try to use dots between sentences. Your answer is not very understandable.

Comment: Besides not being very understandable, the answer is also completely wrong.